# The issue to define Pyomo set on networkx method

Tags: python, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on the directed graph by using the Networkx package and what I need is to use its predecessors' method on an optimization model. Let's say, there exists a directed graph just with 12 nodes. The problem is as follows:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(
    [(1, 2), (1, 3), 
     (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), 
     (3, 6), (3, 7), 
     (4, 9), 
     (5, 9), 
     (6, 8),
     (7, 11),
     (8, 9), (8, 10),
     (9, 12),
     (10, 12),
     (11, 10),
     ])
pos1 = graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
nx.draw(G, pos1, with_labels=True, node_size=800, alpha=0.5)

number_of_station = 4
processing_times = [3, 6, 7, 6, 4, 8, 9, 11, 2, 13, 4, 3]

I = range(len(G.nodes()))
B = range(number_of_station)
predecessors = numpy.array(G.predecessors)

m.I = Set(initialize= I)
m.B = Set(initialize= B)
m.S = Set(initialize= S)
m.PAIRS = Set(initialize = m.I * m.I, dimen=2, filter=lambda m, i, j: (i,j) in predecessors)

m.x = Var(m.I, m.B, domain=Boolean, name= "x", bounds=(0, 1))
m.y = Var(m.B, domain=Boolean, name= "y", bounds=(0, 1))
m.cycle = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, name= "c.t", bounds=(0, 1000))

m.OBJ = Objective(expr = m.cycle, sense = minimize)
m.c1 = Constraint(m.I, rule=lambda m, i: sum(m.x[i,b] for b in m.B) == 1)
m.c2 = Constraint(m.B, rule=lambda m, b: sum(m.x[i,b]*processing_times[i] for i in m.I) <= m.cycle)
m.c3 = Constraint(m.PAIRS, rule=lambda m, i, j: sum(m.x[i,b]*b for b in m.B) <= sum(m.x[j,b]*b for b in m.B))
```

When I run the model it does not show any throw, but the results are incorrect. I guess it came from the definition of the above PAIR set (!) and how it can be used on constraint 3. I am wondering if, someone can guide me to fix that.

Also, as a second attempt, I have tried another form of precedence relations, but the solver returns the following issue:

```
S= [[1, 2], [1, 3],[2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6],[3, 6], [3, 7],[4, 9],[5, 9],[6, 8],[7, 11],[8, 9], [8, 10],[9, 12],[10, 12],[11, 10],]

m.c3 = ConstraintList()
for (i,j) in S:
m.c3.add(sum(m.x[i,b]*b for b in m.B) <= sum(m.x[j,b]*b for b in m.B))
```

the issue:
`KeyError: "Index '(12, 0)' is not valid for indexed component 'x'"`

Indeed for the following, the issue is the same as the first one:

```
for i in m.I:
  for j in m.I:
    if (i, j) in enumerate(S):
      m.c.add(sum(m.x[i,b]*b for b in m.B) <= sum(m.x[j,b]*b for b in m.B))
```

The correct solution:

```
Objective = 20

----------------------
                 1           2           3           4

    1        1.000
    2        1.000
    3                    1.000
    4        1.000
    5        1.000
    6                                1.000
    7                    1.000
    8                                1.000
    9                                            1.000
    10                                           1.000
    11                   1.000
    12                                           1.000
```

Comment: the code you posted has syntax errors, so it doesn't show the issue you want to express.  Suggest you edit (and test run) the code to make sure it is reproducible

Comment: @AirSquid, please, see this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U2F5Wc1W63f7Oi7_yWlghnwK89NgL1DG?usp=sharing).

Comment: It really isn't clear what to look for here or what is incorrect about the results or how a constraint is violated.  Can you clean up the example code above a bit (not an external link) and point out what the violation/issue is more clearly?

Comment: @AirSquid, I just updated the question. Now, you can play around with the mentioned in the question. If you would need more information, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The code you edited is still non-functional.  You just pasted together a bunch of lines.  `m` is not instantiated.  `S` is not defined.  There are no imports...  The code you post when troubleshooting an error should (a) have no syntax problems and (b) produce the error you want help with